# Arrastrar formula en todo un rango de filas hacia abajo con macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, macros

Tengo un problema que creo es sencillo pero no he podido solucionarlo, en otro post vi algo relacionado pero no logro adaptarla para que no solo arrastre la fórmula de una celda en la fila seleccionada si no que tambien me arrastre cada fórmula de cada celda de las filas que defina en esto, adicional que en la última fila no me copie la fórmula hacia abajo del rango si no que tenga el valor fijo de esta creo que es utilizando un .formulaR1C1, la macro que estoy utilizando sin poder aun tener lo que quiero es esta

```html
Sub ArrastrarDatosGEO_SEGMENTO()
    Set a = Sheets("GEO_SEGMENTO")
    a.Range("C3", "C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("C3").Formula
    a.Range("D3", "D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("D3").Formula
    a.Range("E3", "E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("E3").Formula
    a.Range("F3", "F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("F3").Formula
    a.Range("G3", "G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("G3").Formula
    a.Range("H3", "H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("H3").Formula
    a.Range("I3", "I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("I3").Formula
    a.Range("J3", "J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("J3").Formula
    a.Range("K3", "K" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("K3").Formula
    a.Range("L3", "L" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("L3").Formula
    a.Range("M3", "M" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("M3").Formula
    a.Range("N3", "N" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("N3").Formula
    a.Range("O3", "O" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("O3").Formula
    a.Range("P3", "P" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("P3").Formula
End Sub
```

les agradezco su ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, tu rango `C3:P3` tiene una fórmula, y lo quieres arrastrar todo hacia abajo.

Prueba así, a ver si es lo que buscas:

```
Sub ArrastrarDatosGEO_SEGMENTO()

Set a = Sheets("GEO_SEGMENTO")

Dim UltimaFila As Long

With a
    UltimaFila = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("C3:P3").AutoFill .Range("C3:P" & UltimaFila)
End With


End Sub
```